# WSO2 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.JMSContext

Tags: wso2, osgi, osgi-bundle, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

In our company we use WSO2 EI V6.4.
I made the configuration sur connect to azure service bus   with this [guide](https://medium.com/@shefandarren.173/integrating-microsoft-azure-service-bus-with-wso2-enterprise-integrator-b504895ccfe6) and all is working

Now we have to use the last patched version of EI 6.4, and when i made the same configuration, I get this error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/JMSContext
        at org.apache.qpid.jms.jndi.JmsInitialContextFactory.getConnectionFactoryDefaults(JmsInitialContextFactory.java:202)
        at org.apache.qpid.jms.jndi.JmsInitialContextFactory.createConnectionFactories(JmsInitialContextFactory.java:133)
        at org.apache.qpid.jms.jndi.JmsInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(JmsInitialContextFactory.java:103)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactory.initJMSConnectionFactory(JMSConnectionFactory.java:176)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactory.<init>(JMSConnectionFactory.java:154)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactoryManager.loadConnectionFactoryDefinitions(JMSConnectionFactoryManager.java:89)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactoryManager.<init>(JMSConnectionFactoryManager.java:76)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSListener.doInit(JMSListener.java:70)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportListenerEx.init(AbstractTransportListenerEx.java:62)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.ListenerManager.init(ListenerManager.java:84)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:412)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.start(CarbonServerManager.java:220)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreServiceComponent.activate(CarbonCoreServiceComponent.java:105)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.registerHttpService(Activator.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.addProxyServlet(Activator.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.init(ProxyServlet.java:40)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.init(DelegationServlet.java:38)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1184)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1078)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5380)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5680)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1689)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1679)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.JMSContext cannot be found by qpid_jms_client_0.32.0_1.0.0
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:455)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 53 more
```

I try to debug the osgi bundle to understand the problem, and i see that he try to use the bundle **org.eclipse.osgi_3.9.1.v20130814-1242 [0]** instead of bundle **org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-jms_2.0_spec_1.0.0.alpha-2 [139]**

```
osgi> p javax.jms
javax.jms; version="0.0.0"<org.eclipse.osgi_3.9.1.v20130814-1242 [0]>
  hapi_2.1.0.wso2v1 [75] imports
  openjpa-all_2.2.2.wso2v1 [130] imports
  org.eclipse.core.expressions_3.4.500.v20130515-1343 [144] imports
  org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.9.0.v20130326-1255 [146] imports
  org.wso2.carbon.event.core_4.6.49 [263] imports
  org.wso2.carbon.logging_4.4.36 [338] imports
  org.wso2.ei.samples_6.4.0 [579] imports
  qpid_jms_client_0.32.0_1.0.0 [590] imports
  smooks_1.5.1.wso2v4 [604] imports
  spring.framework_3.2.9.wso2v1 [608] imports
  synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v80_29 [612] imports
  synapse-samples_2.1.7.wso2v80 [616] imports
  tomcat_7.0.85.wso2v1 [620] imports
javax.jms; version="0.0.0"<geronimo_jms_1.1_spec_1.1.0.wso2v1_1.0.0 [68]>
javax.jms; version="2.0.0"<org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-jms_2.0_spec_1.0.0.alpha-2 [139]>
  axis2-transport-jms_2.0.0.wso2v30_3 [20] imports


osgi> b 590
qpid_jms_client_0.32.0_1.0.0 [590]
  Id=590, Status=ACTIVE      Data Root=/home/bertrand/DEV/wso2/wso2ei-6.4.0/wso2/components/default/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/590/data
  "No registered services."
  No services in use.
  Exported packages
    org.apache.qpid.jms; version="0.0.0"[exported]
    org.apache.qpid.jms.exceptions; version="0.0.0"[exported]
    org.apache.qpid.jms.jndi; version="0.0.0"[exported]
    org.apache.qpid.jms.message; version="0.0.0"[exported]
    org.apache.qpid.jms.message.facade; version="0.0.0"[exported]
    org.apache.qpid.jms.meta; version="0.0.0"[exported]
    org.apache.qpid.jms.policy; version="0.0.0"[exported]
    org.apache.qpid.jms.provider; version="0.0.0"[exported]
    org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.amqp; version="0.0.0"[exported]
    org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.amqp.builders; version="0.0.0"[exported]
    org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.amqp.filters; version="0.0.0"[exported]
    org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.amqp.message; version="0.0.0"[exported]
    org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.failover; version="0.0.0"[exported]
    org.apache.qpid.jms.sasl; version="0.0.0"[exported]
    org.apache.qpid.jms.selector; version="0.0.0"[exported]
    org.apache.qpid.jms.selector.filter; version="0.0.0"[exported]
    org.apache.qpid.jms.selector.parser; version="0.0.0"[exported]
    org.apache.qpid.jms.transports; version="0.0.0"[exported]
    org.apache.qpid.jms.transports.netty; version="0.0.0"[exported]
    org.apache.qpid.jms.util; version="0.0.0"[exported]
  Imported packages
    javax.naming.spi; version="0.0.0"<org.eclipse.osgi_3.9.1.v20130814-1242 [0]>
    javax.jms; version="0.0.0"<org.eclipse.osgi_3.9.1.v20130814-1242 [0]>
    javax.naming; version="0.0.0"<org.eclipse.osgi_3.9.1.v20130814-1242 [0]>
  No fragment bundles
  Named class space
    qpid_jms_client_0.32.0; bundle-version="1.0.0"[provided]
  No required bundles
```

is it possible to force tu use bundle 68?

Thank you

Comment: try to force version="2.0.0", in your bundle's manifest might help.

Comment: the qpid lib has allready this version configure in manifest, but WSO2 don't care about the manifest if i put it in lib directory. And if i put lib in dropins directory wso2 read the manifest but i get a class not found on **org.apache.qpid.jms.jndi.JmsInitialContextFactory**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had similar problem and used version of `qpid-jms-client-0.11.1` thats works for me. I get it from [this Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.qpid/qpid-jms-client/0.11.1)

Comment: I made a first test, and it's seem to work. This version of qpid need version 1.1 minimum and not 2.0. I'll do more test to validate this solution. Thank you

Comment: it's work thankyou

Answer (score 0):

With the help of support of WSO2 i got an other solution.

1. Use qpid version `qpid-jms-client-0.32.0.jar`
2. Remove lib `geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.0.wso2v1.jar` from `$WSO2_HOME/lib`
3. Remove lib `geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.0.wso2v1.jar` from `$WSO2_HOME/dropins`
4. Ensure that the line `javax.jms` is not present in file `$WSO2_HOME/conf/etc/launch.ini`